# Show starting and ending marker of Polyline on GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

GSMapView in iOS has different functionality to overlay the polyline on the Google map. Is there a way to show the markers at the start and end of the polyline? A Polyline has points that are nothing but string.

```
// MARK: - Polyline
struct Polyline: Codable {
    let points: String?
}
```

Is it possible to extract the first and last point and add them as markers on Google Map?

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining your path for the polyline?

You can define the path of your polyline as `GMSMutablePath()` where you can add coordinate values to define the start and end points of your polyline.

For example, you can define a polyline from Melborne to Perth:

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.addLatitude(-37.81319, longitude: 144.96298)
path.addLatitude(-31.95285, longitude: 115.85734)
let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
polyline.geodesic = true
polyline.map = mapView
```

Then, you can use these coordinates to add a marker exactly on the start and end point of the polyline:

```
let melbourneMarker = GMSMarker();
melbourneMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -37.81319, longitude: 144.96298)
melbourneMarker.map = mapView;

let perthMarker = GMSMarker();
perthMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -31.95285, longitude: 115.85734)
perthMarker.map = mapView;
```

For your reference, you may check this [polyline documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#customize_a_polyline). And, as a result, it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Assume that, I just have polyline and nothing else. Using polyline, we can draw on the google map. But from the polyline itself, I want to extract the starting and ending points.

Comment: May I know where you are getting the polyline? How is the path defined for that specific polyline?

Comment: some other team has created a framework that provides the polyline details to the module that I am handling.